# Display Last Modified Sql Table in jtable

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

I'm making a program in java that makes queries into SQL and show the result in a jtable, my problem is if i do Insert, delete or update i want my jtable to show the sql table that was modified, is there any function for that?
 This is  my method to execute the query:

```
  public void executequery() {

            try {
                String userQuery = Query.getText();
                Statement statement;
                statement = conn.createStatement();
                statement.execute(userQuery);
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(userQuery);
                //in case of a instert, delete or update i want to show
                //the modified sql on my jtable
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                rs.close();
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want your JTable to show updated changes made to the table record(s) within the database as they happen?

Comment: when i do one of those querrys my jtable ends up empty, i want to fill it with the table that was modified

Answer (score 0):

**I you have large number of tables**

you can use an external table called lastModified and use a  db trigger in every insert update delete operation and update the table on above operations.

now map a table name with a unique id and update the record lastUpdatedTime column in every operation.

get the first record of result ordered by time.

that will be the last updated table.

table format

**| id | table_name | last_updated_time |**

Comment: this is my solution, you can simply search about db triggers, rest things are very usual about db operations.

Comment: Can CallableStatement be a solution?