# How stackoverflow stores code snippets

Tags: database, database-design, architecture

This might be a pretty basic question, but how does stackoverflow store the code snippets posted by users? Is each snippet just a DB entry with a text field and userid + postid?

Comment: Good question, but this belongs on Meta.  Unless you have a general question about how one would do this in general on any website.

Comment: I'm working on a similar project, so I'd like to know how websites do this in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the HTML code for a different [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561095/display-last-modified-sql-table-in-jtable).

```
<p>I'm making a program in java that makes queries into SQL and show the result in a jtable, my problem is if i do Insert, delete or update i want my jtable to show the sql table that was modified, is there any function for that?
 This is  my method to execute the query:</p>

<pre><code>  public void executequery() {

            try {
                String userQuery = Query.getText();
                Statement statement;
                statement = conn.createStatement();
                statement.execute(userQuery);
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(userQuery);
                //in case of a instert, delete or update i want to show
                //the modified sql on my jtable
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                rs.close();
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
</code></pre>
```

You have a couple of choices here.

You could save the HTML + text in the database with a question id + user id as the key.

You could use a type indicator to save the text and code separately, and use the indicator to create your HTML.

Either way would work.